# How to uniquely identify all rows in a MySQL table without a primary key?

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, row, primary-key

I use MySQL (in NodeJS). I have a table with unknown data.

I present the data as an HTML table by looping out the items. Then I add a click event to the cells. When that happens I want to load the data from the current cell.

How can I do that?

#### What I could do (but don't want to)

I could let the user add a `custom_identifier` to specify that in this table, use the id as identifier.

```js
/*
From click event. I click on the cell with `column slug` with `id 3`.

cell = {
  identifier: 3,
  column: slug,
};
*/
const custom_identifier = "id";
const sql = `SELECT ${cell.column} FROM WHERE ${custom_identifier} = ${cell.identifier}`;
```

Because this approach requires the user to specify the identifier for each table, I don't want to use this approach.

#### Problem

When making SQL queries and wanting a particular row, we need a `WHERE` statement and an identifier to get the correct row. Some tables don't have an id or even a unique identifier at all.

#### Question

How can I get the data from a row where I don't know an id?

#### Ideas

- Is there a kind of index I could use that is not bound to a column name?
- I can add more stuff to my data attributes in the HTML if needed, index or something else. I just don't want to put the load on the user.

Comment: You can query the information schema

Comment: I'm thinking like me, I try every possible way to even create an artificial data to be used for the query first; if I can't use it in `WHERE`, I make it in `SELECT` using `CASE` then filter it in `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` etc. As long as I still think that it's possible to do with plain MySQL query, I'll try it.. so do you think it's possible to do it in plain MySQL query?

Comment: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` to see what the table is like.  (and show us)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110#1895127) to add a row number to each row. Here's an example of it being used to generate an ID column with incrementing integer values starting from zero:

```
SELECT @idvar := @idvar + 1 AS id,
       tbl.*
FROM tbl, 
     (SELECT @idvar := -1) alias;
```

As the order of results from a `SELECT` isn't guaranteed, you may need to use this to create either a temporary table or a non-temporary table that is later deleted - e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl AS 
SELECT @idvar := @idvar + 1 AS id,
       tbl.*
FROM tbl, 
     (SELECT @idvar := -1) alias;
```

*Note: You'll get a "Duplicate column name 'id'" error if `id` is already the name of an existing column in the table. So unless you know this can't be the case it could be worth going with a more obscure column alias name, e.g. `id_zyxwv` or some other gobbledygook.*

See working demo here: https://rextester.com/DVRGNM12570

Comment: It looks like THE solution to my problem. Thanks! You mention temporary table and non-temporary table. I wonder why you use the non-temporary table in this case?

Comment: It just depends when you might need to read the data - if you can guarantee it will only be used within the same database connection (session) then by all means go for a temporary table. I went with a non-temporary table in the example in case this can't be guaranteed.